# How do I count the percentage makeup of TRUES in a table?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, summarize

This is the code used to derive the first table in my question.

```
JH %>% group_by(ATT_ID, CAR=="B") %>%
summarize(count = n(), .groups = "drop")
```

| ATT_ID | CAR == "B" | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ONE | FALSE | 1 |
| TWO | TRUE | 1 |
| THREE | TRUE | 3 |
| THREE | FALSE | 5 |
| FOUR | FALSE | 2 |
| FIVE | TRUE | 4 |
| SIX | TRUE | 8 |
| SIX | FALSE | 4 |

**How can I get the table above to look like:**

| ATT_ID | Percentage of "B" |
| --- | --- |
| ONE | 0% |
| TWO | 100% |
| THREE | 37.5% |
| FOUR | 0% |
| FIVE | 100% |
| SIX | 67% |

- Notice how some ID's are seen twice so as to show the presence of both FALSE & TRUE whereas other ID's appear once to showcase the presence of only one or the other.

Thank you

Comment: If you are looking for SQL recommendations, please be explicit about it, one cannot rely on the tag alone to communicate your intentions (too often it is an incorrect tag). If not SQL, please remove the [tag:sql] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grouped by 'ATT_ID', get the `sum` of `Count` where `CAR=="B"` is TRUE and divide by the `sum` of full `Count`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ATT_ID = factor(ATT_ID, levels = unique(ATT_ID))) %>%
  summarise(Percentage_of_B = paste0(round(
      sum(Count[`CAR == "B"`])/sum(Count) * 100, 1), "%"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  ATT_ID Percentage_of_B
  <fct>  <chr>          
1 ONE    0%             
2 TWO    100%           
3 THREE  37.5%          
4 FOUR   0%             
5 FIVE   100%           
6 SIX    66.7%
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ATT_ID = c("ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "THREE", "FOUR", 
"FIVE", "SIX", "SIX"), `CAR == "B"` = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), Count = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 
8L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Could I ask the reasoning behind applying levels()?

Comment: @Antonio it is just that with group by, by default, it does reorder the values of 'ATT_ID' in alphabetic order.  So, I changed it to `factor` with `levels` specified as the order of first occurrence with `unique`